# How to randomly change the font size in a WinForms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make the letter size change randomly every time you press the button. Here is a code that randomly shows the letter, the color of the letter

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Color[] co = new Color[4] { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Orange };
    int a;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Random rnd = new Random();
    char[] letters = "АБВГДЕЄЖЗИІЇЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯ".ToArray();
    string output;

    void generate(int NoOfLetter)
    {
        output = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfLetter; i++)
        {
            output += letters[rnd.Next(0, letters.Length)];
        }
        textBox1.Text = output;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rndcol = new Random();
        a = rndcol.Next(0, 4);
        textBox1.ForeColor = co[a];
        generate(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...by randomly changing a property of the textbox, a property that specifies the size of the text in the textbox. Have you taken a look at the [official documentation for TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox) to see which properties it has and whether there is a property amongst them that can help you?

Comment: You may want to look at `RichTextBox`'s `SelectionFont` property: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cfe47e4-7451-43b8-9270-967ca57b2296/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-single-letter-within-a-string?forum=csharplanguage / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0):

The principle is quite similar to the way you randomly changed the foreground color in your code.

A WinForms [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.8) has a property: [`Font`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.font?view=netframework-4.8#system-windows-forms-control-font), that you can access to change **all font attributes including size**.

In order to keep the current font properties *except size* you can use:

```
float fontSize = ... // determine randomly or otherwise
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, fontSize);
```